# Owl-Carousel 2.3.4 with lazyLoad and autoWidth

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I have the [`owl-carousel`](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) plugin on my website, but I would like to offer many images without making the initial page load heavier. I can do this with the `lazyLoad` option ([official demo](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/lazyLoad.html)), but mixed to the `autoWidth` option the images are instantly loaded.

In the example linked below there is the version with `autoHeight` and with `autoWidth`. The first works correctly (the images don't have the `src` tag until they are shown), in the second case (with `autoWidth`) all the images have the `src` tag immediately, and this makes loading the page heavy (and `lazyLoad` useless).

Note: *Drag images for scroll*

**[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7roLjgue/3/)**

**Internal snipped example** (the same of JSFiddle).

```js
var totImg = 15;
var countWimgs = 0;
var countHimgs = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Create images for owl-carousel (h/w)
  for (var i = 0; i < totImg; i++) {
    var width = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 300);
    var src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/' + width + 'x250/0000FF/ffffff?text=Image+' + i + '+-+' + width + 'x250';
    $(".owl-carousel.h").append('<img class="owl-lazy" data-src="' + src + '" />');

    src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/' + width + 'x250/FF0000/ffffff?text=Image+' + i + '+-+' + width + 'x250';
    $(".owl-carousel.w").append('<img class="owl-lazy" data-src="' + src + '" />');


  }

  // Init owl-carousel autoHeight after 2sec
  setTimeout(function() {

    $('.owl-carousel.h').owlCarousel({
      /*loop: true,*/ // Disable for better test with correct total images count
      margin: 25,
      autoHeight: true,
      center: true,
      items: 3,
      mouseWheel: true,
      lazyLoad: true,
      lazyLoadEager: 1,
      onLoadedLazy: function(event) {
        countHimgs++;
      }
    });
  }, 2000);

  // Init owl-carousel autoWeight after 2sec
  setTimeout(function() {

    $('.owl-carousel.w').owlCarousel({
      /*loop: true,*/ // Disable for better test with correct total images count
      margin: 25,
      autoWidth: true,
      center: true,
      items: 3,
      dots: true,
      lazyLoad: true,
      lazyLoadEager: 1,
      onLoadedLazy: function(event) {
        countWimgs++;
      }
    });
  }, 4000);


  // Check SRC tag in <IMG>
  setInterval(function() {

    var countSrcH = $('.owl-carousel.h').find('img.owl-lazy[src]').length;
    $('.hImgs').html('- Images loaded: ' + countHimgs + '/' + totImg + '<br/>Total &lt;img&gt; with src tag: ' + countSrcH);

    var countSrcW = $('.owl-carousel.w').find('img.owl-lazy[src]').length;
    $('.wImgs').html('- Images loaded: ' + countWimgs + '/' + totImg + '<br/>Total &lt;img&gt; with src tag: ' + countSrcW);

  }, 500);


});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 4%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.owl-stage {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-box;
  display: box;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 4%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container.h {
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.container.w {
  background-color: #FFAAAA;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<h3><b>lazyLoad & autoHeight</b> <span class="hImgs"></span></h3>
<div class="container h">
  <div class="owl-carousel h"></div>
</div>

<h3><b>lazyLoad & autoWidth</b> <span class="wImgs"></span></h3>
<div class="container w">
  <div class="owl-carousel w"></div>
</div>
```

*Anyone have a solution? Thanks*

Comment: Owl carousel won't know where to put the next image if it doesn't know the width of the last image, and it won't know the width of the last image until it loads to it just loads everything at once. What you're asking for seems impossible unless you statically know the width of each image.